# Maintaining button selected state inside cell

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uitableview

Lets say I have 3 cells inside a collectionview.  Inside the cell is a follow button, where the `isSelected = true` state has the title `following` and the `isSelected = false` state has the text `follow`.

The first and third button has a `isSelected` state of `false`, and the second button has an `isSelected` state of `true`.  That makes it false, true, false.

The trouble is, I want to maintain these states when the collection view is reloaded.  Whenever I call pull to refresh inside my collectionView, it will read json and load data into the collectionView. Because of how cells are reused, it ends up reloading the previous cell.

So originally, the order would be false, true, false of `isSelected` state. This would then change to false, false true because of how the cells are reused.

Then, once I make another request to check of what the state of the button should be, it changes back to false, true, false.  But, I want to maintain the state rather than having to check the state. Otherwise, it looks buggy. For a split second the `isSelected` state of the button is incorrect.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {


    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: UserCell.reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! UserCell

    cell.user = user?[indexPath.row]
//            cell.followButton.isSelected = false

    return cell

}
```

.

```
class UserCell: UICollectionViewCell {

var user: User? {
    didSet {
        followButton.user = user
    }

    lazy var followButton: FollowButton = {
        let button = FollowButton()
        return button
    }()
}
```

.

```
class FollowButton: UIButton {

var user: User? {
    didSet {
        checkIfUserIsFollowed()
    }
}

override var isSelected: Bool {
    didSet {
        self.layer.backgroundColor = isSelected ? UIColor.rgb(50, green: 205, blue: 50).cgColor
                                                : UIColor.white.cgColor
    }
}

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    layer.cornerRadius = 4
    layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
    translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    setTitle("Follow", for: .normal)
    setTitle("Following", for: .selected)

    contentEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(5,5,5,5)
    titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue", size: 13.0)
    contentHorizontalAlignment = .right

    setTitleColor(UIColor.rgb(50, green: 205, blue: 50), for: .normal)
    setTitleColor(UIColor.white, for: .selected)

    layer.borderWidth = 0.5
    layer.borderColor = UIColor.rgb(50, green: 205, blue: 50).cgColor
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}


func checkIfUserIsFollowed() {
    // This is a request that checks where the logged in user is following the user inside the cell.  It either returns true or false and sets the state accordingly
}

}
```

Comment: Could you provide realization of your `func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, 
      cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell`method?

Comment: @TarasChernyshenko done

Answer (score 0):

To efficiently achieve this you need to save user data for following list. Then compare these with the data getting from api at the time of polulating data in tableview. Or you have to update data on server in real time and update table with only server data.

Comment: So I have an array of userId's that the user currently follows that is fetched before the user fetches the users from the server.  Then, I compare the userIds with the id's of the fetched users?

Answer (score 0):

Not necessarily server side is needed. You can maintain an array of Bool. Length of array = Number of items. On selecting a button update array with the opposite value.

For example: Initially your array looks like [false, false, false]

On selecting button in first cell. Update array with [false, true, false] and simultaneously keep a check in cellForItemAt if value at the index of array is true show following else show follow.

Comment: So I'd be managing two different arrays? an array of `user` and an array of `isFollowed`?

Comment: Your user Array is Array of Dictionaries?

Comment: Nope, user array is just an array of users

Comment: So, if it is then in your user object you can keep a key-value for your self. User["isFollowing"] = false initially and then update it on didSelect and keep a check in cellForItemAt for this value pair. If true show following else follow.

Comment: Can you post a sample data ?

Comment: but every time I load a user into a cell the `isSelected` state is going to be false. So every single cell will be false for a second until i check whether the user if followed, which will be a separate request

Comment: I'm guessing the easiest way is to check and return server side rather than making 2 requests from inside the application

Comment: So server side you must be updating some parameter when a user clicks on follow button. Keep a check on that key value pair.